# Restore screen keyboard to large size

Tags: ipad, keyboard, ipados

In iPadOS 14.2, the on-screen keyboard has shrunk to a tiny size appearing on the left side. Apparently this is a new feature for one-thumb typing.

How can I restore the large size, filling width of iPad?

[image]

Comment: drag it to the bottom of the screen or pinch out.

Comment: @Allan Yes, dragging that grey hyphen-shaped handle to the bottom of the screen restores my keyboard to full-width. Thanks.